# How to override Windows.Forms.Checkbox (image/paint) to a custom checkbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm trying to find a way to override the current UI of the Windows checkbox by replacing to another component that I already have (built).

Basically the component is based on Bunifu Framework and I want to replace the default Windows checkbox with this new one.

```
Windows.Forms.Checkbox (Before)
Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox (After)
```

The reason I need to override the OnPaint method, is because I'm currently populating a DataGrid with a column (bit - data type) that shows a checkbox (1 for checked and 0 for unchecked).

Can anyone help me how to override it with a pre-built component?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure overriding OnPaint is what you need, because by the time that's called the control has already been created, and you can't change the type. A [custom DataGridView column type](https://www.codemag.com/article/0707061) might be a better idea.

Comment: DGV CheckBoxcolumns do use __a normal Checkbox during input__ and only display pixels (ie no controls!) otherwise but you can't control which it is. you can only grab its handle and influence the behaviour (probably incuding Paint, not sure there, but again: only during input ie while in edit mode) but you can't change the type. So the whole idea can only work as @stu suggests ie by creating a custom dgv column. Be prepared for a lot of work..

Comment: @Taw and stuartd thank you for your comments.
I think I'll leave that improvement when I'll make migrate my WinForms to Web Forms!